# django objects filtering according to date

Tags: django

lately I have faced this situation in Django and can not understand clearly why there is difference between these 2 kind of queries
is anybody could help me to understand it, thank you

```py
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> Contract.objects.filter(deadline_on__gt=date).count()
220
>>> Contract.objects.filter(deadline_on__month__gt=10, deadline_on__year__gt=2019).count()
30
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query will get you the results ***greater than 2020-11***

- 2020-12, 2021-01, 2021-02, 2021-04, 2021-04 and so on

But, the second query is a tricky one, ***It only matches with month 11 and 12 and year greater than 2019***

- 2019-11, 2019-12, 2020-11, 2020-12, 2021-11, 2021-12 and so on